# Github API: How to check if repository name available?

Tags: php, github, repository, github-api

how I may check using Github API if name (user input) for new repository are available?
Only try to create repository with http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create ?
Or there are better way?

Comment: As far as i know there is no other way, only checking the error messages sent back.

Comment: Why don't you check it in the list: http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories ?

Comment: Thx, geting repo list or repository is good idea.

Comment: These checks only work if you exclude the fact that all private repositories share the same name poll as the public ones. You might not see the name in the list but it may have already been used as a private repo for another user for which you don't have access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use list-methods?

1. [GET /user/repos](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories) - list repositories for the authenticated user.
2. [GET /users/:user/repos](http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-user-repositories) - list public repositories for the
   specified user.

Answer (score 2):

Besides checking the repositories (which could take a while if the user has a large number of repositories) you can also issue a `GET` against `/repos/:user/:repo`. If you get a `404` then either it does not exist or you're not allowed to view the repository. If you get a `200` then it does exist. It's also going to save your ratelimit.